# Custom Control event not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom button that have hover / click effect. I dont know why mouse events not working with this. Overriden event handlers in class definition still works.

Here is XAML of custom control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSOCodeBox_WPF">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HoverButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HoverButton}">
                 <Rectangle x:Name="btnImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                     <Rectangle.Fill>
                         <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Image}"/>
                     </Rectangle.Fill>
                 </Rectangle>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="btnImage" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HoverImage}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="btnImage" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PressImage}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>                        
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Add control to main window:

```
<my:HoverButton x:Name="hoverButton1" Width="201" Height="121" Canvas.Left="235" Canvas.Top="500" Image="/CSOCodeBox_WPF;component/GFX/Button_None.png" HoverImage="/CSOCodeBox_WPF;component/GFX/Button_Ready.png" PressImage="/CSOCodeBox_WPF;component/GFX/Button_Clicking.png" MouseDown="hoverButton1_MouseDown_1"></my:HoverButton>
```

Event:

```
        private void hoverButton1_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, try using PreviewMouseDown event instead of MouseDown.

Preview events are raised before normal (routed) events in WPF, and many things can suppress the later. The suppression can come from many places, but you can almost always be sure that you can handle a Preview event.

Comment: Btw what would suppress routed events?

Comment: @BienPham What I can say directly is that these two types are not independent. First, the tunneling (Preview) event such as PreviewMouseDown fires first, and while tunneling, this could be suppressed. But if a tunneling event manage to get to the source object that fired it, a bubbling (normal) event such as MouseDown would fire from the source and flow up to the top level element (Window).

As to what would suppress the events, some of the elements up your hierarchy might be the reason. But you can always handle tunneling events. :)